# Creating new, first, phonegap Android project on mac returns error: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I installed the all the recommended programs from [PhoneGap's Getting Started Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) and followed the various steps.

I created the **.bash_profile** file and it looks like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-mac/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-mac/sdk/tools
```

The Development folder is located on my desktop. Upon navigating in terminal to my `bin` directory and creating a new PhoneGap project, i did like so:

```
./create /Users/joey/PhoneGapExample nl.symvoli.phonegapExample PhoneGapDemo
```

I get the following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

I searched around what might cause this problem and everything seems to be pointing to value of the $PATH environment variable. When i ran `echo $PATH` in my terminal, it returns this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Development/android-sdk-mac/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-mac/sdk/tools
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm on a Mac, running Mac OSX 10.8.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just command this in terminal/console

```
export PATH=${PATH}:"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools":"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools"
```

check with `echo $PATH` and you show this

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools:/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: i required to add "tools" location besides the ones i already had (build-tools and plattform tools) thanks!

Answer (score 5):

have you executed the ./create script with sudo?
if you run the script with sudo:

```
sudo ./create .....
```

you have another environment setted.

otherwise you have to export `ANDROID_BIN` variable

```
export ANDROID_BIN=/<your_android_sdk>/tools/android
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me the issue was that I had set the PATH variable as described in step 3 of the tutorial, but I made a mistake and the PATH I specified was actually wrong.
So if it does not work with sudo, you might want to try and check the path again.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran `./create` I immediately received an error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

If you open up the create file (phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/bin/create) with textEdit, there is a line that lists

`ANDROID_BIN=”${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}”`.

The “which android” is the cause of the issue

If you replace this line with the full path to your android tools (SDK), it should resolve the issue. It looked like this:

```
ANDROID_BIN=/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/android
```

Hope this could help someone!

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this

1.

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

2.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:"/Users/**username_here**/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/**username_here**/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools"
```

3.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

1. Close Terminal, open Termial again and ...

just like found in here: http://yandr.randy.boy.jp/?eid=6
didn't understand a word but saw the last link and it worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue, in my configuration (mac pro + android studio) the sdk path was "/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk". The problem is how you specify in "export $PATH=..." a new path added (/Application/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools and so on), seem that using '"' work with export $PATH for bash but does not work with script "create" with Phonegap. My end solution it's to move sdk in an alternative directory without blank in is name.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of a wrong PATH. Refer this [blog post](http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2013/12/an-unexpected-error-occurred.html)